# Find a best fit curve for a function f(x) = g(x+1)/g(x)-g(x+1)

Tags: r, regression, splines

I have a set of noisy data that can be described by a functional form.

For each observation f(x), where x is an index that runs from 0-100, I know that f(x)=g(x+1)/g(x)-g(x+1). I would like to find a way of fitting f(x). I also know that f(x) must be smooth. How could I do this?

My idea is to try and fit this data using penalized splines. I choose a spline basis and a smoothing factor, and then find the coefficients of a regression on the spline basis that produce a curve f(x). I then optimize the coefficients to produce a curve such that when it is transformed it fits my data. A minimal reproducible example in R is below.

```
require(dplyr)
require(gam)

target = c(0.132167681875765,0.804942648636132,0.60485585022111,1.02164234486286,0.58437549344597,0.88268397325963)

to_optim = function(par,target,knots,smooth,range) {

spline_reg = function(range,knots,par) bs(range,knots) %*% par

distance = function(fitted,target,smooth) sum((fitted-target)^2) +t(as.matrix(diff(fitted))) %*% 
  (as.matrix(diff(fitted))) * (smooth)

fitted = spline_reg(range,knots,par)

crs = fitted/lag(fitted)-fitted
crs=crs[3:length(crs)]
target=target[3:length(target)]

to_ret = distance(crs,target,smooth)

return(to_ret)

}



my_range = seq(1,6)
mypars = 4
smooth=.8

fit = optim(c(runif(mypars)),to_optim,lower=c(rep(-10,mypars)),
            upper=c(rep(10,mypars)),smooth=smooth,knots=mypars,target=target,range=my_range,
            method="L-BFGS-B")


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
bs(my_range,mypars) %*% fit$par %>% plot

test = bs(my_range,mypars) %*% fit$par
plot(test/lag(test)-test~target)
abline(0,1)
```

Comment: What can you say about $g(0)$ or $g(101)$? You need to know something about the boundary conditions to solve this difference equation.

Comment: Let's be more specific: given  the $y(i)$ and almost any value for $f(0)$, you can iteratively solve $$f(x+1)=\frac{y(x)}{1/f(x)-1}$$ and obtain a *perfect* fit. (There will be up to $100$ invalid values for $f(0)$, but no more than that.) That makes this both an underdetermined problem and a non-statistical question because it makes no consideration whatsoever of any errors in the measurements.  Since you asked it here, I suspect you may be concerned about the effects of such errors. What can you say about them? Could you tell us where this functional form comes from?

Comment: Can you make the notation in your question body and title consistent, please? You're using $f$ on the LHS in the title and on the RHS in the body. There's no need to risk the potential confusion of someone trying to substitute one equation into the other to write $y(x)$ as a very complicated function of $g(x)$'s.

Comment: @Whuber - sure. These are ratios of the one year probability of death to the ratio of the deaths. This is a demography problem I am working on. It's hard to specify an error model, but I would say that the r.v. G(x) =gx+ex+zx. Where gx is the actual amount; ei is a symmetrically distributed error term and  zx is a right skew error term such that zx is zero except where x is a specific number, say multiples of 5 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know $g(0)$ or $g(101)$ you can solve this difference equation. You may know the value of $g(0)$ or of the difference $g(1)-g(0)$ etc.

For instance, if $g(0)=c$ then 
$$f(0)=g(1)(1/c-1) \rightarrow g(1)=f(0)/(1/c-1)$$
$$f(1)=g(2)(1/g(1)-1)\rightarrow g(2)=f(1)/(1/g(1)-1)$$
etc.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, given that I have not given enough information in my question to justify why I want to use splines.